# macOS SwiftUI: how to trigger deleting an item?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am working on my very first SwiftUI app on macOS Monterey 12.6 using Xcode 14.2.
I have created a new *Multiplatform* > *App* project (enabling Core Data) and Xcode generated a working sample app.
The view part looks like this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                NavigationLink {
                    Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                } label: {
                    Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
        }
        .toolbar {
#if os(iOS)
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                EditButton()
            }
#endif
            ToolbarItem {
                Button(action: addItem) {
                    Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            }
        }
        Text("Select an item")
    }
}
```

Adding new items by clicking the `+` button works - but how do I delete them ?

I suppose the sample code is mostly generated with iOS in mind; I tried running the app on an iPhone simulator: Deleting there just happens as usual by swiping the item in the list.

However, on macOS it seems I need some other means to trigger the deletion.

I have added a `ToolbarItem` / `Button` analogous to `Add Item` and Xcode also generated this `deleteItems` function:

```swift
private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
    withAnimation {
        offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

I figure on iOS, this function gets called somehow automagically via the `onDelete` *modifier* (?).

I imagine I could try to get the index of the item in the list, turn that into an `IndexSet` somehow and connect calling `deleteItems(...)` to the delete button, but I have a gut feeling SwiftUI provides some much simpler way for such a standard task - after all, that's CRUD on the Core Data model...

I tried to get sample code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67334152), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72405436), [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-let-users-delete-rows-from-a-list) and [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-delete-core-data-objects-from-swiftui-views) to work, but I clearly seem to lack the SwiftUI experience required to understand the code and adapt it for my needs.

How do I trigger deleting an item ?

Comment: Rather than updating this question with your new problem of creating a delete button, I'd recommend posting a new question, and include a [mcve] of how you tried to do this.

Comment: I have also edited my answer with a working, more complete example. The problem with your code might be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this `List` were *not* in a `NavigationView`, you would have been able to swipe left with 2 fingers on a row, and see the delete button. Clicking that will trigger the `onDelete` modifier.

However, since the list is in a `NavigationView`, and macOS displays it and the navigation destination in a "split" way, similar to a `NavigationSplitView`. In this mode of presentation, there is no swipe with 2 fingers gesture.

Also note that `NavigationView` is deprecated in the newest version of macOS. You should use `NavigationSplitView` if you want a "split" presentation.

If you use a `NavigationStack`, which only shows the navigation links, and only shows the destination if you click on one of them, then the swipe left with 2 fingers gesture is supported.

Otherwise, you will have to come up with your own UI of deleting things. You can take inspiration from how existing macOS apps do it. For example, in the Notes app, the navigation bar has a "trash" button.

[image]

You can consider putting this into your `toolbar`:

```
Button {
    withAnimation {
        selection.forEach(viewContext.delete)
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "trash")
}
```

where `selection` is set up like this:

```
@State var selection = Set<Item>()
// ...
List(selection: $selection) {
    // ...
}
```

A more complete example:

```
@State var items = ["1", "2", "3"]
@State var selection = Set<String>()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { (item) in
                NavigationLink {
                    Text("Item at \(item)")
                } label: {
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem {
                Button {
                    withAnimation {
                        items.removeAll(where: { selection.contains($0) })
                    }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                }
            }
        }
    }.onChange(of: selection) { newValue in
        print(newValue)
    }
}
```

An alternative is to add a `contextMenu` item for deleting items, similar to how the Contacts app does it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@Sweeper's update with the more complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76457058), I was able to figure out the problem (in the end, simply by comparing on a text basis ): The `ForEach(...)` loop in my code was missing an `id: \.self` argument:

```swift
// doesn't work, `selection` never is set
ForEach(items)
```

```swift
// works
ForEach(items, id: \.self)
```

I don't understand *why* `id` is required, it is never used in the code; must be some Apple / SwiftUI / Swift / whatever black magic - somewhat frustrating, but I guess that's the learning curve for you . More on `id: \.self` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76457058).

So, in conclusion, the steps required to amend an Xcode-generated sample project to delete items on macOS are as follows:

1. add a `selection` state variable:

```swift
@State private var selection = Set<Item>()
```

2. pass `selection` to the `List` in `NavigationView`:

```swift
List(selection: $selection) {
  ...
```

3. pass `id: \.self` to the `ForEach` loop:

```swift
ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
    ...
```

4. add a `ToolbarItem` for the *trash* button, analogous to the generated `Add Item` item:

```swift
ToolbarItem {
    Button(action: deleteItem) {
        Label("Delete Item", systemImage: "trash")
    }
}
```

5. add the `deleteItem` function for the button above to call, analogous to the generated `addItem` item:

```swift
private func deleteItem() {
    withAnimation {
        print("delete button clicked")
        // TODO: BUG - upon deleting a second item,
        // selection contains first and second item
        print("selection: \(selection)")
        // NOTE: sample code from @Sweeper's answer:
        //   items.removeAll(where: { selection.contains($0) })
        // fails with a bunch of inscrutable error messages, e.g:
        // + Cannot call value of non-function type 'Binding<Subject>'
        // + Referencing subscript 'subscript(dynamicMember:)' requires ...
        //    ... wrapper 'Binding<FetchRequest<Item>.Configuration>'
        // --> adapting approach from generated deleteItems(...) function
        selection.forEach(viewContext.delete)

        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

AFAICT, an `onChange` modifier is not required for selecting and deleting itself; it might however be useful to fix the bug mentioned in the comment in the code above.